# Saving any object to Keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I want to save an object which might include sensitive data into the keychain. To achieve this i will convert this object into a NSData instance.

I'm a bit confused which attributes i need to use. Is it ok to use **kSecClassGenericPassword** as **kSecClass** even though it is not really a password? Furthermore i've set the **kSecAttrAccount**. I've read somewhere that i also need to add **kSecAttrService**. What implications can happen if i don't ?

Comment: I have stumbled on the very same issue, I cannot store an NSObject into the keychain, looks like it can only store passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) on GitHub. It's a nice Open Source wrapper for the keychain that makes it super easy to use. If you want to understand more about how the keychain and the security on iOS/OS X work and you're registered to the Apple Developer Program, there are few WWDC session videos that you might check on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com).

Comment: Actually i'm stuck with a custom implementation for accessing the keychain. My question is more about if it is okay to misues the kSecClassGenericPassword for an arbitary object or if there is any other attribute to use.

Comment: There's a list you can check in the Keychain Services Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. SSKeychain is for storing NSStrings. A better option is this https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain

Answer (score 0):

[Strongbox](https://github.com/granoff/Strongbox) is using NSKeyedUnarchiver to convert any type conforms to NSCoding to NSData object before save into keychain.